# Requesting CarPlay entitlement

Tags: ios, carplay

The documentation from apple states:

1. Select Identifiers in the menu on the left.
2. Select your app’s App ID.
3. Choose the Additional Capabilities tab.
4. Enable the CarPlay capabilities that your app requires.

There is no Additional Capabilities Tab anymore and no media kit or car play options on the capabilities tab. Am I missing something?

[Indentifiers page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38jFo.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The account holder of your developer program needs to request the entitlement [here](https://developer.apple.com/contact/carplay/) explaining why it makes sense to use CarPlay for your app

Comment: Does anyone have experience with how long a response should take? I made my request 7 days ago and have heard nothing.

Comment: @garafajon How long did it finally take time to get an answer?

Comment: @AmineG after 2 weeks it got approved

Comment: @garafajon While requesting CarPlay Entitlement with AppStore team small description is enough in the "Tell us about your app" section or More details we need to provide? (I mean complete flow details). Because, I requested two weeks ago. No respond yet.

Answer (score 0):

Share my personal expireince:

Jan 22, 2024 I asked Apple to CarPlay entitlements, described idea of my app and draw some example screenshots (with Figma). And Feb 24 they approve my request with this email.

[image: CarPlay entitlement approve]

So, it takes about 1 month in my case.